# ASP edit config.xml location

Tags: xml, config

I recently took over a website, and organized the folders in such a away that all my includes weren't in order however i managed to change this. But one of the asp pages cannot find the config.xml in the root folder.

Error Code:
`Unable to load config file: 'The system cannot locate the object specified. ' (-2146697210)`

I think i have identified the code in the .asp file for finding and loading the config but i dont not know how i can change this to point it to the new location of the config file:

`Public Sub Load DefaultXML

```
    If IsNull(stPath) Then
        stPath = Server.MapPath("/")
        stPath = Left(stPath, InstrRev(stPath,"\", Len(stPath)-2))   & "config.xml"
    End If
    LoadXML stPath  
End Sub
```

I found a post which had the same error as me but for a different function, the solution to the post was to install the latest msxml6.dll from:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=6276

Now when i refresh i just get a white screen, no content loaded, no errors shown.

Any help would be extremely! appreciated!

Thanks!